# How to get short lived access to specific Google Cloud Storage bucket from client mobile app?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-storage

I have a mobile app which authenticates users on my server. I'd like to store images of authenticated users in Google Cloud Storage bucket but I'd like to avoid uploading images via my server to google bucket, they should be directly uploaded (or downloaded) from the bucket.
(I also don't want to display another Google login to users to grant access to their bucket)

So my best case scenario would be that when user authenticates to my server, my server also generates short lived access token to specific Google storage bucket with read and write access.

I know that service accounts can generate accessTokens but I couldn't find any documentation if it is a good practice top pass these access tokens from server to client app and if it is possible to limit scope of the access token to specific bucket.

I found authorization documentation quite confusing and asking here what would be best practice approach to achieve access to the cloud storage for my case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for signed urls.

> A signed URL is a URL that provides limited permission and time to
>   make a request. Signed URLs contain authentication information in
>   their query string, allowing users without credentials to perform
>   specific actions on a resource.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#overview) you can see more about them in GCP. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually)  you have an explanation of how you can adapt them for your program.

Comment: Does that allow operation only on single image or it can be used to for example download multiple different images with same signed URL. (I would need access for multiple download and upload)

Comment: Hey Matej, i don't think that at the current moment you can use one Signed URL for multiple files, because you point directly to the object when you generate them.

[More info](https://medium.com/google-cloud/upload-download-files-from-a-browser-with-gcs-signed-urls-and-signed-policy-documents-f66fff8e425)

Let me know.

Comment: Would this method of signing urls work fast enough for example if in my app user starts scrolling and I needs to quickly download significant number of thumbnails (small files)?

Comment: If you are worried about load times, you could prefetch the images so that they are ready to be displayed while the users scroll down. Additionally you can check the product [Cloud CDN with signed urls](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls) which is made to serve static content on such cases.